# MySQL indexing columns altogether or one by one?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

Which one is better?

```
ALTER TABLE `messages` ADD INDEX(`user_id`, `recipient_id`);
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE `messages` ADD INDEX( `user_id`);
ALTER TABLE `messages` ADD INDEX( `recipient_id`);
```

And why?

Comment: Indexes are intended to make queries faster.  One set is not "better" than another, unless you have specific queries you want to speed up.

Comment: @GordonLinoff "unless you have specific queries you want to speed up." Please explain this part.

Comment: These are different indexes. The first creates **one index on both columns** together - the 2nd is one index on `user_id`and another one on `recipient_id`. Depends what you want.

Comment: @Alexander Is there any benefit on creating index on multiple columns together?

Comment: @TrondroMulligan . . . I think the MySQL documentation actually explains this pretty well:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html.

Comment: More discussion in [blog about compound indexes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1) and [cookbook for creating indexes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two statements do *very* different things.  The first one is a composite index (think like indexing the concatenation of both fields) while the second one defines two independent indexes.

As such, neither is better, but likely only one is appropriate for your specific situation.

Comment: In the above scenario, which one do you think is more appropriate?

Comment: that depends on the queries, frequency profile, keyspace distribution, etc.

Comment: Suppose this query. "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user_id=1 AND recipient_id=2"; Which indexing is better for this type of query?

Comment: In this scenario, a composite Index would be *better*, but are these the only queries you'll have? If you could as well have queries that only have WHERE clauses on `user_id` or `recipient_id`, separate indexes would be *better*. Keep in mind that each index slows down write (e.g. inserts), but speed up read operation (SELECT)